# Static assets from cdn in nuxt.js problem with link

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to serve my static assets from s3. I created on AWS a bucket where I keep my project and cloudFront for it.

In nuxt.config.js in build section I've defined publicPath which is my CNAME from cloudFront for example `https://assets.eglebegle.com`

```
build: {
       publicPath: 'https://assets.eglebegle.com'
 }
```

But on webpagetest I've see link to the bucket on s3:  `https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/eglebegle/dist/3723d572a5470dd8435b.js.`

Is there any way to change that? I would like to see `https://assets.eglebegle.com/dist/3769d572a5470dd8435b.js`

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt is not building `static/` folder. Only `assets/` folder is building.